# Proper Method For Setting Up One-to-One in CodeIgniter Datamapper

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I am reviewing all of my models and corresponding tables for CodeIgniter Datamapper. I'm wondering what the correct way of setting up a one-to-one relationship with a defined parent and child is. The way I have been doing it is similar to this:

```
class Customer ... {

  public $has_one = array('address');

}

class Address ... {

  public $has_one = array('customer');

}
```

with the Customer being the parent (ie, has either one or zero Addresses) and the address being the child (always has one Customer). In the database I have a customer_id on addresses which is not null, indexed and associated with customer.id and set to CASCADE on update and delete , and address_id on customers which is null and associated with address.id and set to NO ACTION on update and delete.

Is this the proper configuration for a CI Datamapper one-to-one-or-zero (parent/child) relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good explanation in the [FAQ section of the docs](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/troubleshooting.html):

> When configuring a relationship, even a self-relationship, you must define both "sides" of the relationship. This means for a parent/child relationship, you have to specify the parent on the child, and you have to specify the child on the parent.
>   Here is an example for a complex self-relationship [User (as Boss) has many Employees, and Employees have one Boss]:

```
// In User
$has_one = array(
    // define the relationship to the boss
    'boss' => array(
        'class' => 'user',
        'other_field' => 'employee'
    )
);

$has_many = array(
    // define the relationship to the employees
    'employee' => array(
        'class' => 'user',
        'other_field' => 'boss'
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm not certain how it answers my question - how do I tell DM which is parent and which is child?

Comment: The model doesn't care who's parent/child... maybe you want to use the [Nested Sets Extension](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/extensions/nestedsets.html)?

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. Coincidentally, I'm employing a 'report_to' structure using a self-referential relationship in DM to achieve the same type of thing elsewhere in my app. But this is too much for this particular use - I only want to define a parent. But it looks like I can leave that up to my RMDBS using constraints and whatnot. I appreciate your taking the time to help.